# Making one array exactly equal to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];
var array2 = [4, 5, 6];
```

I want array 1 to be exactly equal to array 2. I've been told I can't simply do:

```
array1 = array2;
```

If I can't do this, how can I make array1 equal to array2?

Thanks

Comment: `array1 = array2.slice(0)`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do `array1 = array2;`?

Comment: @Patrick I'm not sure, it's what a friend said. Can I do that?

Comment: Yes you can do that. I'll post an answer with the results. You could have tried it yourself.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you just need a copy of the elements of an array you can simply use slice like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
copyArray = a.slice(0)
[1 , 2 , 3]
```

As for why you should not use assignement here look at this example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a 
a.push(99)
a 
[1,2,3,99]
b
[1,2,3,99]
```

If you copy an array you don't have this problem:

```
 a = [1,2,3]
 b = a.slice(0)
 a.push(888)
 a 
 [1,2,3,888]
 b 
 [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Does this have the exact same effect as doing 'copyArray = a'?

Answer (score 2):

For a deep copy of your array, do this ([REFERENCE](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/deep-copying-of-objects-and-arrays/)):

```
function deepCopy(obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]') {
        var out = [], i = 0, len = obj.length;
        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            out[i] = arguments.callee(obj[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        var out = {}, i;
        for ( i in obj ) {
            out[i] = arguments.callee(obj[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
var clone = originalArray.slice(0);
```

Comment: Is this the same as doing clone = originalArray?